# Unable to view the Login Page on keycloak

Tags: java, reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am working over integration of React application with KeyCloak. I have installed the keycloak server version 11.0.2 over my local machine. I am able to access the administrative login and create the admin user. I have also created a custom client and user with credentials using the keycloak. My react application is hosted over port 9000 of my machine and keycloak over 8080 (default) port. Now, when I am redirecting to my application URL it is automatically redirecting to the below url:

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{Custom_realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id={Custom_Client}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2F&state=r8yy83fdgd-27f8-4aa9-a679-01sfdsgd9&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=27fedfgf89-66be-4484-bbcc-aabb4saddc4
The url is rendering We are Sorry and not allowing me to enter the credentials required for the user.

[image]

Not sure why is the login page not landing.
Can anyone help me out with this?? Also provide the basic level of configurations required for Keycloak for integrating it with the application and creating a new Realm and client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved. There was a mismatch of the Realm name in the code as well as the one created in Keycloak. In Keycloak I created UI_Realm while in code it was written as UI_realm